# Being redirected to login.php inside of loading the assigned url

Tags: php

I am being redirected to login.php after login in instead of being redirected to the assigned url. But when I remove the protection code which make sure you have to login before the assigned page would load it works fine but when i insert the protection code, it keeps taking me back to login.php. What might be the problem. Here is the script.

Here is the protection code:

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();

    //Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
    if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) || (trim($_SESSION['login']) == '')) {
        header("location: login.php");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Here is the login-exec.php script

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('config.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Connect to mysql server
    $link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //Select database
    $db = mysql_select_db($dbname);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $login = clean($_POST['login']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);

    //Input Validations
    if($login == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Login ID missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    //If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: login.php");
        exit();
    }

    //Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM bslogin WHERE username='$login' AND password='".md5($_POST['password'])."'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    $data=array("norendb7" => array("url"=>"insideonbanking-1.php"
                                    ,"password"=>"yasinmy20")); 

    if(isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password'])) { 
        if($data[$_POST['login']]['password'] == $_POST['password']) { 
            $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login'] . " " . $_POST['password']; 
            header('Location: ' . $data[$_POST['login']]['url']); 
            exit();            
        } else {
            //Login failed
            header("location: login.php");
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To check whether the session is even being started or not and what is in `$_SESSION`, insert `<?php var_dump($_SESSION); ?>` on top of the login.php page then login form the login form.
this will tell you what is in `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you hardcode `$data` and don't use the your database results (in `$result`). And you should really use a framework, btw.

Comment: and the other half of the world, says a framework would be bloated overkill.

Comment: Not those who have ever done maintenance or extending large php applications. There _are_ lightweight frameworks like Kohana. See http://goo.gl/6jVKS

Comment: It's all I have done for a living for over a decade, and I have never used a framework. I Don't want to argue, i just don't think statements to newbies like "you should really use a framework" are very useful